# Пройти по списку в списке и вернуть другой список в Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть класс MembersGroup с полями (String groupName, List members) и в нем класс Member с полями(String name, Integer age). Если что, к каждому полю соответственно есть геттеры для связи с остальными классами.
Работа должна производиться в другом классе в спешл методе

```
Set<String> findOldMembers(List<MembersGroup> groups, int targetAge)
```

где groups это группы, а targetAge - некоторое значение возраста
Надо при помощи Stream API вывести в новый список имена тех memberов, которые старше targetAge.

Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать.
Тут мой план действий, но не знаю, верный он или нет, а если да, то как это объединить все?

```
   Что надо сделать?
   1. Пройтись по списку групп groups grous.stream()
   2. Пройтись по списку людей в группах members members.stream()
   3. Отфильтровать member-ов по getAge .filter(x -> x > targetAge) (чем-то дополнить)
   4. Создать лист с getName оставшихся .getName().collect(Collectors.toList) (???)
   5. Вернуть список
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<String> findOldMembers(List<MembersGroup> groups, int targetAge){
    return groups.stream()
            .flatMap(t->t.getMembers().stream())
            .filter(m->m.getAge()>targetAge)
            .map(m->m.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```